# http error when installing glueviz in conda-forge channel

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I've just installed the most recent Anaconda 3.4.3.0 on windows 7
and I want to install glueviz so I followed the steps in the 
[glueviz installation guide](http://glueviz.org/en/stable/installation.html)

I couldn't add conda-forge from the graphical view in Anaconda Navigator. 
I had the message in the image [image]

And when I tried to install it from the Anaconda prompt using `conda install -c conda-forge glueviz`I had this message :

```
Fetching package metadata ... 

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <None>

Elapsed: None 

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",),),)
```

Can anyone help me install glueviz ?

Thanks

Comment: In fact I couldn't install any package...

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `.condarc` file located in your `Miniconda3/Anaconda3` root directory. There should be a line with just a hyphen.

This line corresponds to the `None` channel. Deleting the line fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't have a line with just a hyphen. I think I have a proxy problem..